# Reading consequent text files by using arrays in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to read values and write it to where I want from 4 thousand different text files.

As an example the fine name is like `NACA63220_1.30_17_CD.txt` and `NACA63220_1.05_12_CL.txt`
In this name, the value `1.30` changes, `17` changes and `CD` becomes `CL` etc.

I want to create loops so that I read and paste the value I want from these files one by one.

```
Mach = Array ("0.2_", "0.6_", "0.9_", "1.05_", "1.30_")
Alpha = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
Letter = Array("_CD", "_CL", "_CM")

strFile = D:\Database\NACA63220_ + Mach(5) + Alpha(18) + Letter(1) .txt
```

I want to have something like this with loops so that in this instance this `strFile` becomes `D:\Database\NACA63220_ 1.30_17_CD.txt` and then I can continue with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate strings with `&` not `+` (which is for calculation only). Also your strings need to be enclosed in quotes `""`.

```
strFile = "D:\Database\NACA63220_" & Mach(5) & Alpha(18) & Letter(1) & ".txt"
```

Note that depending on how your arrays were defined the counting starts with zero `0` not with `1`. So the last item is `Mach(4)` not `Mach(5)`. In this case …

```
strFile = "D:\Database\NACA63220_" & Mach(4) & Alpha(17) & Letter(0) & ".txt"
```

should give the desired result `D:\Database\NACA63220_ 1.30_17_CD.txt`

Comment: So I can put i, j and k to the array paranthesis and use them in loop right?

Comment: yes but your loop needs to start from `0` probably. You can use `For i = LBound(Mach) To UBound(Mach)` to loop from first item of `Mach` to the last item.